# Display LocalNotification as an alert

Tags: ios, cordova

I am setting an alert in my app which results in a local notification which is displayed as a banner.  How can I make it display as an alert that has to be clicked to dismiss it or ideally open the app directly?

This is how i am currently setting the notification

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        id: 'happicards' + id, 
        title: "Your Happi Card Awaits", 
        message: "Click to view", 
        repeat: repeat, 
        date: alarm_date          
  });
```

Comment: There must be some way to set alert type for local notification, just find the right text to use on google. Hop this help you.

//to set button on right of alert

localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a user setting.
Open device

> Settings > Notifications > Your App

and adjust to your personal preference. In other words: can not be done.

But you can send silent Notifications to your app and execute code when they get in. This will allow at least parts of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, at least useful to know to stop trying.